# trouble getting internet while connecting to home Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have troubles connecting my laptop to the home Wi-Fi.
when I'm trying to connect to the network i see the message "no internet, connected" no matter if I'm close to the router, even though other devices do get internet.

**details**:

Lenovo ideapad 130-15IKB laptop,
windows 10,
network adapter: Qualcomm Atheros Communications Inc QCA9377,
driver version: 12.0.0.927

I've tried to update the windows version and to connect an internet cable but it didn't work as well.
I am able to get internet from my phones' hotspot.

route print:

```
Interface List
  3...9c 5a 44 2e ac de ......Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
 22...3e 91 80 22 dd f1 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #3
 16...4e 91 80 22 dd f1 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #4
 20...3c 91 80 22 dd f1 ......Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: try disabling bluetooth to see if the problem resolves; **if** your qualcomm device driver settings has a setting for antenna selection for either blutetooth or wifi, set it to something other than auto (experiment). BT and WiFi are both in the same general transmission frequency and they can jam each other.

Comment: Can you communicate with other devices on your local network? Do you get an IP address or is it something like _169.254.x.x_? // What happens on a wired connection? Same?

Comment: I see a newer driver [12.0.0.1016](https://www.ath-drivers.eu/download-driver-for-Atheros-chipset-with-id-104-and-Windows10-64bit.html) that you could try.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: thanks for the quick responses, Yorik-  I disabled my bluetooth still the same issue. Daniel- I pinged another computer in the same network successfully. Harry- I downloaded it successfully, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @inbar could you open `cmd.exe` and edit your question with the output of `route print`?

Comment: If local network is fully functional and it works using your phone hotspot, your device could be blocked from accessing the internet in your router. Check for that maybe.

Comment: @mashuptwice I added it

Comment: @inbar It seems to me that you don't have a default route set for IPv4

Comment: @mashuptwice can you please explain how to set it?

Comment: @inbar - The route would be handled by the gateway you have connected to.  If you are getting "no internet, connected" while connected to the access point, it's the access point, which doesn't have access to the internet.  Your phone if connected to a provider, is a poor test device, since it will fallball to your cellular service provider to access a page.

Comment: If you do not have any route, ping could not work either. Are you sure ping works? Having this few routes is very unusual. In the network connection’s properties, are you sure IPv4 is enabled as a protocol?